# Many to Many relationship get all grouped records

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I have the following three tables in a mysql database:

grades:

| id | st_id | Q1 | Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20001 | 93 | 89 |
| 2 | 20002 | 86 | 84 |
| 3 | 20003 | 82 | 83 |
| 4 | 20001 | 86 | 89 |
| 5 | 20002 | 89 | 54 |
| 6 | 20003 | 81 | 94 |

subjects:

| id | subject | yr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | English | 2023 |
| 2 | Math | 2023 |
| 3 | Science | 2023 |

grades_subject:

| sbj_id | st_id | grd_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20001 | 20001 |
| 1 | 20002 | 20002 |
| 1 | 20003 | 20003 |
| 2 | 20001 | 20001 |
| 3 | 20002 | 20002 |
| 2 | 20003 | 20003 |

The grades table contains an id (primary key) student_id and quiz scores. A student_id can appear multiple times in this table.

The Subjects table is a simple list of subjects with a primary key.

The grades_subject table links the two with a subject id, grade id (The st_id links another table with student information). All three are a primary keys.

As you can see, a subject id can appear many times in this table as each student in the grades table can have multiple subjects. 20001 appears twice, once with subject id 1 and again with subject id 2 etc. Each subject id can also appear numerous times as numerous student_ids in the grades table can share one subject.

Im tyring to get all records in the grades table, grouped by subject id. So the result would be:

sbj_id 1...then all the students in that class with their respective grades.
sbj_id 2... and so one for all subjects.

I have tried various solutions from this site and many combinations of different types of joins, groupings and also used select distinct. I either get duplicate values, or the correct records in the grades table but only 2 subject_ids, or student grades getting repeated for each subject and other inaccurate results.I have also tried subqueries.

This is the closest I have gotten to the correct results (I understand I do not neet the group by grades_subject.sbj_id in the below query, its just to demonstrate that it works):

```
SELECT grades.*, grades_subject.sbj_id
FROM grades
JOIN grades_subject ON grades.st_id = grades_subject.grd_id
where grades_subject.sbj_id = 49
group by grades_subject.sbj_id, grades_subject.grd_id
```

It results in all the scores for all students in that class which demonstrates that with my current setup I should be able to get what I am looking for with the right query or grouping. When I remove the where clause, I should get each sbj_id, and then all students in that subject with their scores, then the next subject etc. However, it will retrieve the scores for the first student in the subject, then duplicate those results for all other students in that subject as shown below:

| sbj_id | st_id | Q1 | Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20001 | 93 | 89 |
| 2 | 20001 | 93 | 89 |
| 3 | 20001 | 93 | 89 |
| 4 | 20002 | 93 | 89 |
| 5 | 20002 | 93 | 89 |
| 6 | 20003 | 93 | 89 |

Select Distint does not work, various join types do not work, selecting and grouping by ids in the grades table does not work including the primary id. Instead of listing everything I have tried that does not work...

How I can get my desired results with my current set up without changing my table setup as other tables and coding are built on it. The set up works well with all other types of queries that I need except when Im trying to get all student grades accross all subjects. If I must change the set up, please ellaborate on the simplest way.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anything in the grades table that make it apply to a particular "subject". The student has a grade. As far as I can tell, that's all you know - its a grade for "something".

Comment: Note that since you are writing plain sql I don't think the tags for sqlalchemy or mysql-python are relevant.

Comment: Can't be done with published data -perhaps grd_id in junction table has been incorrectly transcribed given it's the same as st_id and the table name is grade_subject but you do need a relationship to grade somewhere

Comment: @topsail, the grades table just lists the student ids, but in the linking table each id is linked to a subject. It works when I select all st_ids from the grades table that have a subject id of 2 in the linking table when I join the tables. I just cant get them to group by subject. id
Also you can answer in sqlalchemy queries, It is a python app. I used pure sql to get try to understand the core issue. I sql alchemy I am able to produce the results I want with schemas but I need to query the database in this case.

Comment: @P.Salmon. It works generally when I select students from the grades table with subject ids from the linking table. eg select * from grades where grades_subject.sbj_id = 2 (after joining) The student id from the grades table is linked to a subject id in the linking table. If it is impossible to get the results I need with this setup, can someone suggest a different many to many relationship setup between the grades table and the subject table. I would prefer to have one linking table that links all student related tables since the student id will be the same in all other student related tables

Comment: The grades_subject table is an example of over normalisation , the grades table is a junction table (eg student table to subject(s) via grades). capture the subject id in grades.

Comment: Why are `st_id` and `grd_id` all exactly the same in `grades_subject`? Your data makes little sense.

Comment: As pointed out by few other, your table structure is all wrong. grade table should have a subject column, you claim that it is working without where because then you get all data mixed up and you focus on limited data been correct. Grades are not linked to subject hence you won't find solution yet. Correct your data first, remove the Last table as that is not needed, but add subject in grade table itself.